# type mismatch when using return keyword

Tags: scala, generics, return-value, return-type

What I understood in `Scala` is that, the last executed instruction of a function/method will be its return value without using the `return` keyword. From these codes I get a mismatch error:

without `return` (no error):

```
def longestSublist[T](p: T => Boolean)(l:List[T]): List[T] = {
   val empty: List[T] = List[T]()
   val (curr, max) = l.foldLeft((empty, empty))((prev, x) => {
       val (_curr, _max) = prev
       if(p(x)) {
            (_curr.:+(x), _max)
       } else {
            (empty, if(_curr.size > _max.size) _curr else _max)
       }
   })
   if(curr.size > max.size) curr else max
}
```

with `return` (error):

```
def longestSublist[T](p: T => Boolean)(l:List[T]): List[T] = {
   val empty: List[T] = List[T]()
   val (curr, max) = l.foldLeft((empty, empty))((prev, x) => {
       val (_curr, _max) = prev
       if(p(x)) {
            return (_curr.:+(x), _max)
       } else {
            return (empty, if(_curr.size > _max.size) _curr else _max)
       }
   })
   if(curr.size > max.size) curr else max
}
```

from what i understood, `foldLeft`'s second parameter should return a type `(List[T], List[T])` but when adding `return` the compiler said

```
type mismatch;
found: (List[T], List[T])
required: List[T]
```

Shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: `return` terminates the `longestSublist()` method, which is _supposed_ to return `List[T]` so it's an error to `return` a tuple.

Comment: `return` returns from the method, not from the lambda. Such confusion is a reason not to use `return` in Scala. https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html

Comment: Ok, thanks i thought it exits the lamda fx